# Javascript: best way to wait for script loaded synchonously before executing function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, loading, synchronous

I have the following problem:
I load a page inside a modal dialog. This page uses jQuery as dependency. Since I already use jQuery on the main page, for me, it is always available. Now we have the usecase, that also different pages (hosted on different domains) need to load that page if necessary.

So, I check if the jQuery variable exists on this page and if yes, just go on with my code.

If it does not exist, on top of the template, I dynamically create a script element like this:

```
<script>
if(!window.jQuery)
{
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.src = "path/to/jQuery";
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
</script>
```

And at the end of the template, I use a IIFE (to scope the jquery variable)

```
(function ($) {
.... code ....
})(jQuery);
```

However, since with this method, the script gets loaded asynchronously, sometimes I get the error: jQuery is undefined.

Now I came up by loading it synchronously, like this:

```
    var xhrObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // open and send a synchronous request
    xhrObj.open('GET', "jquery.min.js", false);
    xhrObj.send('');
    // add the returned content to a newly created script tag
    var se = document.createElement('script');
    se.type = "text/javascript";
    se.text = xhrObj.responseText;
    document.getElementById('placeholder').appendChild(se);
```

This works fine, but the warning "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.  to the end user's experience." made me think.

However, now I changed my code and just said

```
if (!window.jQuery) {
    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="jquery.js"' + '>' + '</scr' + 'ipt>');
}
```

on top of my Template.

Dear javascript gurus, is this a reliable solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use the onload attribute in async javascript

```
<script async src="siteScript.js" onload="window.MyInitialisation()"></script>
```

In javascript it would look like this:

```
<script>
if(!window.jQuery)
{
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.async = "async";
   script.defer = "defer";
   script.onload = function() {window.MyInitialisation()}
   script.src = "path/to/jQuery";
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but async is not an option since it is not supported by IE 9.

Comment: Well, test first if the onload attribute gets triggered in ie. Thats the main thing you're after.